Explain MySQL left join
CREATE TABLE tab1 (
  id1 int NOT NULL,
  field11 int NOT NULL,
  field12 date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

INSERT INTO tab1 (id1, field11, field12) VALUES
(1, 11, '2024-07-10'),
(2, 11, '2024-07-10'),
(3, 11, '2024-07-10'),
(4, 12, '2024-07-11'),
(5, 12, '2024-07-11'),
(6, 12, '2024-07-11');

CREATE TABLE tab2 (
  id2 int NOT NULL,
  field21 int NOT NULL,
  field22 date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

INSERT INTO tab2 (id2, field21, field22) VALUES
(1, 11, '2024-07-01'),
(2, 11, '2024-07-01'),
(3, 11, '2024-07-01'),
(4, 22, '2024-07-02'),
(5, 22, '2024-07-02'),
(6, 22, '2024-07-02');

select * 
from tab1 t1
left join tab2 t2 on t1.field11 = t2.field21;

I got the following result:
+-----+---------+------------+------+---------+------------+
| id1 | field11 | field12    | id2  | field21 | field22    |
+-----+---------+------------+------+---------+------------+
|   1 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    3 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   1 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    2 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   1 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    1 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   2 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    3 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   2 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    2 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   2 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    1 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   3 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    3 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   3 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    2 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   3 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    1 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   4 |      12 | 2024-07-11 | NULL |    NULL | NULL       |
|   5 |      12 | 2024-07-11 | NULL |    NULL | NULL       |
|   6 |      12 | 2024-07-11 | NULL |    NULL | NULL       |
+-----+---------+------------+------+---------+------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

But I expect following result:
+-----+---------+------------+------+---------+------------+
| id1 | field11 | field12    | id2  | field21 | field22    |
+-----+---------+------------+------+---------+------------+
|   1 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    1 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   2 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    2 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   3 |      11 | 2024-07-10 |    3 |      11 | 2024-07-01 |
|   4 |      12 | 2024-07-11 | NULL |    NULL | NULL       |
|   5 |      12 | 2024-07-11 | NULL |    NULL | NULL       |
|   6 |      12 | 2024-07-11 | NULL |    NULL | NULL       |
+-----+---------+------------+------+---------+------------+

My expectations are based on this documentation (from https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_left.asp):

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table
(table1), and the matching records (if any) from the right table
(table2).


The results dataset must be only records that correspond to ONLY the green circle on the picture.
How does this left join work?

for that you need a row_number so that the rows are uniue so you only make a cross join , what you see in the result

You requested all records where t1.field11 = t2.field21, and that is what was returned. If you look at the id fields of each returned entry you can see that the matching pairs are all unique.

on t1.field11 = t2.field21 - For each record in tab1 with a field11 value of 11 there exist three records in tab2 with a matching field21 value.  What you're seeing is the cartesian product of that join.  Three records on the left, each with three matching records on the right, equals nine records.  Plus the remaining three records on the left with no matching records on the right.  Your expectation was simply wrong.

field11 has a row with value 11. field21 has three rows with value 11. The one row of field11 gets joined to all three because your database has no idea which one of the three rows in field21 YOU would like to join. You'll have to be more specific in your join criteria to get to your output. It's VERY important to understand that a table has no inherent ordering. The order you see as a human means nothing. Perhaps you SHOULD be joining id1 to id2 if you want that ouput.

LEFT JOIN is like INNER JOIN, but it adds rows from the first table that have no match in the second table. But in both cases, for rows that have multiple matches, you get all the matches, unless you use GROUP BY to combine them.

on t1.field11 = t2.field21 AND t1.id1 = t2.id2 ?

This question is answered at: What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What is the legend for that diagram? How do we read it? If it's a Venn diagram, what are the kinds of sets & elements & what are the circles & labels & shading? What exactly does that one say? Especially since SQL tables are bags not sets. Those Venn-like diagrams for outer vs inner join are misleading & unhelpful. CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in SQL Venn Diagram for Natural Join What is the difference between “INNER JOIN” and “OUTER JOIN”?

How can a LEFT OUTER JOIN return more records than exist in the left table? LEFT JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN.

You quote an unclear description. You quote an unclear diagram with no legend. You tolerate unclear writing & diagrams. You got those at an unreliable web source. You don't say what you think they say. You don't connect them to your reasoning. You don't give your reasoning. Your description of the expected output is unclear. ("only records that correspond to ONLY the green circle") Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

Yes you are right the LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table, and the matching records from the right table.
Like as you performed left join on 't1.field11 = t2.field21'-
All rows from the left table (t1) will be returned and
rows in tab1 with field11 = '11' will join with all rows in tab2 where field21 = '11'.
Since there are 3 matching rows in tab2 for field21 = 11, each row in tab1 with field11 = 11 will match with each of these 3 rows, leading to multiple combinations. Rest all will be NULL.
